# How to show a text after onPressed function

Tags: flutter

I want to show a text after **onPressed** function happened, this function is a recording function and wants to show a text 'recording' when the function happening

**voiceCreate.dart**

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class VoiceCreate extends StatelessWidget {
      final VoidCallback onPressed;
      VoiceCreate({this.onPressed});
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
            body: Center(
              child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.mic),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  iconSize: 70,
                  onPressed: onPressed),
            ),
          ),
        );
    
      }
      
    }

**main.dart**

import 'dart:io';
import 'package:audioplayer/audioplayer.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:record_mp3/record_mp3.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'regitration.dart';
import 'voiceCreate.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String statusText = "";
  bool isComplete = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Builder(
        builder: (context) => Scaffold(
          drawer: Drawer(
            elevation: 2.0,
            child: ListView(
              children: <Widget>[
                ListTile(
                  title: Text('Home'),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) {
                          return MyApp();
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                ListTile(
                  title: Text('Sign up'),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) {
                          return LoginScreen();
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
                ListTile(
                  title: Text('Sign in'),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) {
                          return LoginScreen();
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                    // add sign in page
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                  return VoiceCreate(onPressed: startRecord);
                }),
              );
            },
            // Add your onPressed code here!

            child: Icon(Icons.add),
            backgroundColor: Colors.tealAccent.shade700,
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade900,
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Myvo'),
            centerTitle: true,
            backgroundColor: Colors.tealAccent.shade700,
          ),
          body: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        child: IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.mic),
                            color: Colors.white,
                            iconSize: 40,
                            onPressed: () async {
                              startRecord();
                            }),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        child: IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.pause),
                            color: Colors.white,
                            iconSize: 40,
                            onPressed: () async {
                              pauseRecord();
                            }),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        child: IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.stop),
                            color: Colors.white,
                            iconSize: 40,
                            onPressed: () async {
                              stopRecord();
                            }),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                  child: Text(
                    statusText,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
                  onTap: () {
                    play();
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                    alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
                    width: 100,
                    height: 50,
                    child: isComplete && recordFilePath != null
                        ? Text(
                            "play",
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 20),
                          )
                        : Container(),
                  ),
                ),
              ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<bool> checkPermission() async {
    if (!await Permission.microphone.isGranted) {
      PermissionStatus status = await Permission.microphone.request();
      if (status != PermissionStatus.granted) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  void startRecord() async {
    bool hasPermission = await checkPermission();
    if (hasPermission) {
      statusText = "Recording...";
      recordFilePath = await getFilePath();
      isComplete = false;
      RecordMp3.instance.start(recordFilePath, (type) {
        statusText = "Record error--->$type";
        setState(() {});
      });
    } else {
      statusText = "No microphone permission";
    }
    setState(() {});
  }

  void pauseRecord() {
    if (RecordMp3.instance.status == RecordStatus.PAUSE) {
      bool s = RecordMp3.instance.resume();
      if (s) {
        statusText = "Recording...";
        setState(() {});
      }
    } else {
      bool s = RecordMp3.instance.pause();
      if (s) {
        statusText = "Recording pause...";
        setState(() {});
      }
    }
  }

  void stopRecord() {
    bool s = RecordMp3.instance.stop();
    if (s) {
      statusText = "Record complete";
      isComplete = true;
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  void resumeRecord() {
    bool s = RecordMp3.instance.resume();
    if (s) {
      statusText = "Recording...";
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  String recordFilePath;

  void play() {
    if (recordFilePath != null && File(recordFilePath).existsSync()) {
      AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
      audioPlayer.play(recordFilePath, isLocal: true);
    }
  }

  int i = 0;

  Future<String> getFilePath() async {
    Directory storageDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String sdPath = storageDirectory.path + "/record";
    var d = Directory(sdPath);
    if (!d.existsSync()) {
      d.createSync(recursive: true);
    }
    return sdPath + "/test_${i++}.mp3";
  }
}
```

VoiceCreate function will happen on a new page when clicking on the Floating button in main.dart and recording will happen when click on mic Icon, want show the text 'recording' whine the fuction happening.

Comment: Can you please clarify more? Show text where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to have `StatefulWidget` to manage changes in state, then you can use two functions `startRecording` and `stopRecording` to toggle the `isRecording` variable. Then based on the value of `isRecording` you can make changes in the view, e.g., displaying a text. For displaying the text you can use a `Visibility` widget and set its `visible` parameter to `isRecording`.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var _isRecording = false;

  _startRecording() {
    this.setState(() {
      _isRecording = true;
    });
  }

  _stopRecording() {
    this.setState(() {
      _isRecording = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        body: Center(
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.mic),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  iconSize: 70,
                  onPressed: () => _startRecording(),
              ),
              IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.stop),
                  color: Colors.white,
                  iconSize: 70,
                  onPressed: () => _stopRecording(),
              ),
              Visibility(
                visible: _isRecording,
                child: Text(
                  'recording',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.red
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a snackbar could be useful here, something like:

```
class VoiceCreate extends StatefulWidget {
  VoiceCreate({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _VoiceCreateState createState() => _VoiceCreateState();
}

class _VoiceCreateState extends State<VoiceCreate> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  var isRecording = false;

  void showRecordingMessage(String message, [Color color = Colors.red]) {
    _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(
        new SnackBar(backgroundColor: color, content: new Text(message)));
  }

  void setRecordingState() {
    this.setState(() {
      isRecording = true;
    });
    print("isRecording is set to $isRecording");
    showRecordingMessage('Recording now!');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.mic),
              color: Colors.white,
              iconSize: 70,
              onPressed: () {
                setRecordingState();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```